# GIT revert invoked problems for child branches

Tags: git

I have master branch & some child branches. There was a wrong commit & push to master, so I hard reverted it to the previous commit.

Now when I try to pull source code from child branches - it gives me error, that source code conflicts (which was in master branch and source code in particular files were not changed).

What I did wrong? How could I resolve this problem? SHA-1 looks OK for master.

Comment: Do the child branches still depend on the old (wrong) version of master?

Comment: Yes, they are. But also some child branches was reverted to very old commit.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but it sounds like your child branches need to be rebased onto the new master

Comment: I have some features development branches, also development & test branches. All branches are child of master branch. I reverted master branch and development branches were kept untouched, while development & test were reverted to older commits. Nobody touched them at all.